Tiled Map not loading in Phaser, getting only the bg color
Following is my code:
demo.json file (exported map from tiled):
{ 
 "compressionlevel":-1,
 "height":16,
 "infinite":false,
 "layers":[
        {
         "data":[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
            0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
            0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
            0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
            0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
            0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
            0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
            0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
            0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
            0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
            0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
            0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
            0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
            0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
            0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
            0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
         "height":16,
         "id":1,
         "name":"layer",
         "opacity":1,
         "type":"tilelayer",
         "visible":true,
         "width":16,
         "x":0,
         "y":0
        }],
 "nextlayerid":2,
 "nextobjectid":1,
 "orientation":"isometric",
 "renderorder":"right-down",
 "tiledversion":"1.11.0",
 "tileheight":64,
 "tilesets":[
        {
         "columns":1,
         "firstgid":1,
         "grid":
            {
             "height":64,
             "orientation":"isometric",
             "width":128
            },
         "image":"assets/tilesets/emp_1.png",
         "imageheight":64,
         "imagewidth":128,
         "margin":0,
         "name":"emp_1",
         "spacing":0,
         "tilecount":1,
         "tileheight":64,
         "tilewidth":128
        }],
 "tilewidth":128,
 "type":"map",
 "version":"1.10",
 "width":16
}

index.html file:
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Phaser Tilemap</title>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/phaser@3.60.0/dist/phaser.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <button id="startButton">Start Game</button>
    <script>
        class TilemapScene extends Phaser.Scene {
            preload() {
                this.load.image('tiles', 'assets/tilesets/emp_1.png');
                this.load.tilemapTiledJSON('tilemap', 'assets/maps/demo.json');
            }
            create() {
                const map = this.make.tilemap({ key: 'tilemap' });
                const tileset = map.addTilesetImage('emp_1', 'tiles');
                const layer = map.createLayer('layer', tileset, 0, 0);
                layer.setVisible(true);
            }
        }

        const config = {
            type: Phaser.AUTO,
            width: 128 * 16,
            height: 64 * 16,
            backgroundColor: '#87CEEB',
            scene: TilemapScene,
        };

        document.getElementById('startButton').addEventListener('click', () => {
            document.getElementById('startButton').style.display = 'none';
            const game = new Phaser.Game(config);
        });
    </script>
</body>
</html>

my console is giving no errors and network gives a 200 status to all requests. i don't know why i can't see the loaded map (which has one tile, trying with many tiles and layers caused the same problem so i decided to start slow and find out the error). i can only see the blue background. please help, been at it for too long.

Wanted to ask is your issue solved? I so  and my answer solved it please consider accepting it. Or if you have a different solution please consider posting your own answer.

Well our code works, the issue has to do with your json file.
You can see, that your phaser-code works, if you change the first values of the data property of the json file, to "1's" like this:
"data":[1, 1,

than you should see something.
Apart from that I assume (from your code and json) you wanted 16x16 tiles, but the definition of the json shows a tilesize of 128x64. if you fix this it should work as desired.
Important: And don't forget index 0 is an empty tile, so you would also have to fix that, if not you won't see anything.
As starting point, you could use these altered json-values:
(Or better yet fix the issue in the Tiled editor)
/* only altered values were kept */
{
/*...*/
"layers": [
    {
    "data": [
        1, 1, 1, /* ... */
    ],
    /*...*/
    }
],
/* ... */
"tileheight": 16,
"tilesets": [
    {
    /* ... */
    "tilecount": 64,
    "tileheight": 16,
    "tilewidth": 16
    }
],
"tilewidth": 16,
/* ... */
}

